# Using ajax to populate dropdown with SQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I am relatively new to ajax , but I have an idea of what is happening. I have a registration form that updates the fields of "country , city and area" using ajax from a database.

The php looks something like this

```
<select disabled name="City" id="City<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"   >
        <?php
            global $wpdb;

            $results = $wpdb -> get_results("SELECT Distinct City FROM Location WHERE Country = '".$selected_country."'");

            foreach ($results as $row)
            {
                echo "<option value=\"$row->City\">" . $row->City. "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
```

and the java script looks like this

```
$("#Country").change (function(){
     var selected_country = $('#Country option:selected').val();
       if (selected_country !=''){
         $('#City').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
          $('#City').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'fetch_city',
                selected_country: selected_country
            }
            })
     })
```

If I change the "url" where the request is sent to myform.php , the result of the drop down is not updated with actual database results. My guess is that I am missing a step.

P.S I am not using the "action" yet as I am not sure if it will be helpful. I did add it to the functions.php file and hooked it dynamically.

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Your $.ajax call is lacking a success function, e.g.

```
success: function(data) {
        $('#City').html(data);
    }
```

However to achieve desired results you have to return appropriate json_encoded results from your database-query.

Comment: My database query happens inside the php file , not the java script , is it possible to do so. without running the query in the JS ? I am not quite sure

Comment: The database access can only happen in the php code you are requesting in your ajax-call via url: ajax_object.ajaxurl. Note that you have to take care about the data format you return from this php, and how you are handling the results back in your javascript/ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of your code is missing or broken? Where is $selected_country coming from for example? You probably don't have any element with the id 'City' either since you're appending whatever is in $template->the_instance() to it.

You also never handle the respone from your Ajax request.

Comment: City is an ID given to another drop down list